# short battery life

Tags: battery-life, battery

I have a gs3 running slim bean, and the battery life seems horrible to me. I woke up this morning at 8:00am with 100% battery life and by 1:30pm it has gone down to 23%  I have been I barely use the phone throughout the day too. The entire time the phone is probably being used for 30 min to an hour the rest of the time the screen is off.

What causes this?

Comment: Hard to say without hard facts. Have you checked the consumers in battery stats? Tried to check if anything keeps it awake all the time (using e.g. [Wakelock Detector](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wakelock-detector-save-battery/com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector) or [BetterBatteryStats](http://www.appbrain.com/app/betterbatterystats/com.asksven.betterbatterystats))? Or monitored your system using an app like [SysPanel](http://www.appbrain.com/app/SystemPanelLite-Task-Manager/nextapp.systempanel)? All these things provide useful clues.

Comment: Also check the [battery-life tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/battery-life/info) for similar top-rated questions, their answers might help you tracking down the culprit.

Comment: Does your GS3 have LTE capability?  If so, are you in an LTE service area?

Comment: It does use LTE, but usually I only get zero or one bar when I am at work or at home.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that GS3 has a quad core processor which uses quite a bit of power.  Also you have 4 radios (GPS, Bluetooth, WiFi and Mobile data.  If you are leaving all the radios on during the work day, you are consuming battery power.  Did you listen to music sometimes during the day....?  Did check Facebook or take pictures?   Which apps to do you have running?  All these features consume power.  You might need to adjust your features - turn off bluetooth and/or GPS and WiFi if you are not using them or close some of the apps. If I am away from a charging station and am listening to music and don't need my GPS or WiFi, I usually turn those features off to conserve battery poweer.

Comment: Even a quad core processor only uses lots of power while it's running at full tilt: if the device sleeps as much as it should, it shouldn't use that much power. Also, merely having GPS turned on in the settings doesn't make the GPS receiver burn energy: it's only powered when an app is actively using it (when the GPS notification is displayed).

Comment: I wasn't implying that just having GPS on uses a lot of power.  I was looking at usage as a whole.  I find that I have a shorter battery life when I have ALL the radios on, just as the user was complaining about.  My suggestion was to turn off any of the un-needed radios in order to conserve power when away from a charging station.

Comment: That's great. I just want to make sure other visitors don't get the idea that having GPS turned on draws power even if no apps are using it, as that's not true.